# www not shown in front of website url.Please help me

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

This is the website www.lenscare.co.in when i click on MEN tab www. no shown in front of url.Please help me. I need www. in front of lenscare.co.in. Its magento 1.9

Comment: www. is useless now why need you it ?

Comment: Why is useless?. because full website is with www. .

Comment: Because you can access a website without `www.`

Comment: i know but my clients want www.. Half site is working with www. and half not.

Comment: Ifyou put www in front of an URL , some browser like chrome will remove them.

Comment: Move your cursor on the MEN tab you will see the full url in the left downside

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your base url in the admin to have the "www" prefix? Check under **System > Configuration > Web** in the admin.

Answer (score 0):

go to .htacess and enter this code

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.yourdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]